# How do I pass data from angular component to another component via router?

Tags: angular

> I'm tried to pass data from angular component to another component via
>   a router. Any elegant solution?

I tried this and it's working.

```
this.router.config.forEach(route => {
    if (route.path === 'pages') {
        route.children.forEach((child) => {
            if (child.path === 'saveName') {
                child.data = {
                    name: "Jack"
                };
            }
        });
    }
});

this.router.navigate(['/pages/saveName']);
```

> And also send a file with data.
>
> Just want to know whether there is a more elegant solution, like the
>   one below.

this.router.navigate(['/pages/saveName'],{"name":"Jack"});

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: I'm using Angular 7

Answer (score 0):

Yes, check out the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters-required-or-optional):

```
this.router.navigate(['/heroes', { id: heroId, foo: 'foo' }]);
```

Comment: We are trying to send a file but this method data pass throw URL, right?

Comment: Using the routing strategy, you can pass only as query parameters in the URL. Use **@Input** decorator to pass data from one component to another component.

Comment: @input decorator can be only used with related components right? ie Parent-child

Answer (score 0):

I think is better solution.Check following above Link.

https://angular.io/guide/router#fetch-data-before-navigating

Answer (score 0):

Angular 7.2 supports passing data via a state object during navigation

You can pass the state object in navigateByUrl method

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/path', { state: { hello: 'world' } });
```

or

Pass Data using routerLink directive

```
<a routerLink="/path" [state]="{ hello: 'world' }">Go</a>`
```

And Read the data using paramMap Observabele to filter only window.history.state

```
 constructor(public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.state$ = this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(
      map(() => window.history.state)
    );
  }
```

Check this link:https://netbasal.com/set-state-object-when-navigating-in-angular-7-2-b87c5b977bb